# Textbox text not retrieving due to encoding

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

I'm using a chinese mobile device which has windows mobile 6.1 to run my .net CF 3.5 application.The problem I'm having is, when I enter text in a custom textbox, I see empty spaces in textbox.text in the code. Can anyone tell me how I could encode the text that is displayed in the textbox?

Comment: You mean it's "spaces" on the device, or in Studio?

Answer (score 0):

If your device is built with the Chinese version of Windows Mobile, it may only have Chinese characters defined.

I have not seen a way on WinMo devices to change the language, so you may be stuck with that.

I don't know if you can read Chinese (I can't), but have you tried using a Chinese version of Visual Studio? Chinese versions of VS and WinMo are difficult to find here in the US (for obvious reasons).